# How to use default values and arbitrary arguments at one function call in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments, default-value

I am learning Python.

I learned about default value and arbitrary arguments.

So, I made my function which has a parameter offering a default value, and another parameter having an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
def make_pizza(size=15,*toppings):
    """Summerize the pizza that we are about to make."""
    print("\nMaking a " + str(size) + 
    "-inch pizza with the following toppings: ")
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)


make_pizza('onion','shrimp','goda cheese','mushroom' )
make_pizza(17,'ham','extra meat','sweet con','pepperoni')
```

At the first function call, I wanted to use the default value for the "size" parameter which is "15" and the "*toppings" arbitrary argument.

But, I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Could anyone tell me when I call a function with multiple arguments, how I can use parameters' default values and arbitrary arguments at one function call?

Sorry in advance if you feel uncomfortable with my English(I am not a native.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mixing parameters with and without default values can indeed be confusing. *Parameters* are the names used in the function definition, *arguments* are the values passed into a call.

When *calling*, Python will always fill all parameters from positional arguments, *including names with default values*. `size` is just another parameter here, even though it has a default value. You can also use `name=value` syntax in a call to assign an argument value to a specific parameter (whether or not they have a default value). But you can't tell Python not to assign something to `size`, not with your current function definition, because everything before the `*toppings` parameter is *always* going to be a regular positional parameter.

The `*toppings` parameter will only capture any positional arguments *after* all the other parameters have received values. So `'onion'` is assigned to `size`, and the remainder is assigned to `*toppings`.

In Python 3, you can make `size` a *keyword-only parameter*, by placing them as `name=default` **after** the `*toppings` name, or an empty `*`:

```
def make_pizza(*toppings, size=15):
```

Now `size` can only be set from a call with `size=<new value>` keyword argument syntax.

In Python 2, you can only capture such keyword arguments with a `**kwargs` catch-all parameter, after which you need to look into that dictionary for your `size`:

```
def make_pizza(*toppings, **kwargs):
    size = kwargs.get('size', 15)  # set a default if missing
```

In both cases, you have to remember to explicitly name `size`, and put such explicitly named keyword arguments *after* the positional arguments:

```
make_pizza('ham', 'extra meat', 'sweet con', 'pepperoni', size=17)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand what was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There's a fundamental problem with your approach: It's ambiguous because how do you know if you intended it as `size` or as `topping`? Python can't do that so you need to find an alternative.

Well, you could simply remove `size` from the argument list and interpret the first `*toppings` argument as size if it's an integer:

```
def make_pizza(*toppings):
    if toppings and isinstance(toppings[0], int):
        size, toppings = toppings[0], toppings[1:]
    else:
        size = 15
    print("\nMaking a {}-inch pizza with the following toppings: ".format(size))
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)
```

However that will fail for cases where a simple type check isn't possible. Maybe the better approach would be to make `toppings` a normal argument and `size` an optional argument:

```
def make_pizza(toppings, size=15):
    print("\nMaking a {}-inch pizza with the following toppings: ".format(size))
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)
```

However then you need to pass in a sequence for `toppings` and it changes the order of `toppings` and `size` but it's probably a lot cleaner.

```
make_pizza(['onion','shrimp','goda cheese','mushroom'])
make_pizza(['ham','extra meat','sweet con','pepperoni'], 17)
```

You could also keep the toppings as arbitary positional arguments and make `size` a keyword-only parameter with default (Python3-only):

```
def make_pizza(*toppings, size=15):
    print("\nMaking a {}-inch pizza with the following toppings: ".format(size))
    for topping in toppings:
        print("- " + topping)

make_pizza('onion','shrimp','goda cheese','mushroom')
make_pizza('ham','extra meat','sweet con','pepperoni', size=17)
```

Comment: You can still keep `*toppings`, there is no need to make it a single argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right, I just thought he wanted `size` as positional argument. Using `*toppings` will make a trailing `size=15` keyword-only (and python-3 only).